# Python Selenium cannot get button from iframe

Tags: python, css, selenium, xpath, iframe

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tAYlX.jpg)I want to click the button called "바카라 멀티플레이" which locates center of the site. I switched into iframe, however it seems to be not detecting the button. How can I?

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common import exceptions
import sys
import asyncio

"""
    Chromedriver Options / Driver setting
"""
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
#ptions.add_argument('headless')
options.add_argument('window-size=1920,1080')
options.add_argument("disable-gpu")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=options)

driver.get('https://ggl-maxim.com/')

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="body"]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/fieldset/input[1]').send_keys('tnrud3080')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="body"]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/fieldset/input[2]').send_keys('tnrud3080')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="body"]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/fieldset/button[1]').click()

time.sleep(2)
driver.get('https://ggl-maxim.com/api/popup/popup_menu.asp?mobile=0&lobby=EVOLUTION')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it("gameIframe"))
driver.find_element_by_class_name(".wrapper--1zUtU").click()
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".svg--1nrnH")))
```

Comment: Try using this xpath `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='wrapper--1zUtU']")` for the button 바카라 멀티플레이

Comment: Check another answer, it should resolve the question you asked in comments. Next time try to formulate the question correctly initially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This    `.svg--1nrnH` does not represent the button you wanna click.
Plus that is a svg element you cannot use just the that css selector to locate the element.

**Code :**

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Users\\***\\**\\Desktop\\Selenium+Python\\chromedriver.exe")
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
driver.get('https://ggl-maxim.com/')

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="body"]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/fieldset/input[1]').send_keys('tnrud3080')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="body"]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/fieldset/input[2]').send_keys('tnrud3080')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="body"]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/fieldset/button[1]').click()
sleep(5)
driver.get('https://ggl-maxim.com/api/popup/popup_menu.asp?mobile=0&lobby=EVOLUTION')
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID,"gameIframe")))
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".wrapper--1zUtU")))
sleep(5)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".wrapper--1zUtU button"))).click()
sleep(5)
print("Operation successful")
```

**O/P :**

[image]

Comment: @famas kim  : Check out this code and let me  if it works for you

Comment: It doens't click the button. I think it need to wait for the delay also.

Comment: Can you add sleep(3) before clicking the button

Comment: Oh, me too. How can I wait for the screen shows?

Comment: are you quitting or closing driver instance ?

Comment: nope  I need to wait until ".svg--1nrnH" shown to get the data

Comment: @famaskim : added few more hardcoded wait, check out the new code

Comment: I've changed the code to click the button, and I have to wait for the loading how can I?

Comment: which loading you are referring to ?

Comment: After the click, the website is loading to get the data

Comment: Does hardcode wait like sleep(60) works for you ?

Comment: tell me the data that you wanna fetch after click ?

Comment: I will post it with picture

Comment: @famaskim Show on a screenshot which elements you are waiting for. As I see it, you do not need to wait for them because they are already loaded...

Comment: yes he wants to grap `baccarat ` data, but I can locate it since I don't understand that language

Comment: I understood what he wants and will post the answer. I suggest this answer to remain accepted as the initial question was answered.

Answer (score 0):

For the login action use the below xpaths. This way your code will look neat.

```
driver.get('https://ggl-maxim.com/')

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@placeholder='아이디']").send_keys('tnrud3080')
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@placeholder='비밀번호']").send_keys('tnrud3080')
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='btn_apply']").click()
```

For the click of button 바카라 멀티플레이, try using the below xpath and see if it works:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='wrapper--1zUtU']").click()
```

Comment: How can I wait for "svg--1nrnH" after clicking the button?

Comment: Because the site is loading to show multipaly chart

Comment: You can add `WebDriverWait` with `expected_conditions`

Comment: `wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 500)`
`wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".wrapper--1zUtU button"))`

Comment: @famaskim What is `".svg--1nrnH` and why do you need to wait for it if it's already loaded.

Comment: I have posted the picture. I need to get the data of baccarat game

Answer (score 0):

After you click that button to get the games list you need to switch to another iframe. There are two iframes with a very similar names, so I used selector which indicates that iframe name starts with `https://evo.kplaycasino.com/frontend/evo/r2/#category"]`.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common import exceptions
import sys
import asyncio

"""
    Chromedriver Options / Driver setting
"""
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
#ptions.add_argument('headless')
options.add_argument('window-size=1920,1080')
options.add_argument("disable-gpu")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/snap/bin/chromium.chromedriver', chrome_options=options)

driver.get('https://ggl-maxim.com/')

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='text']").send_keys('tnrud3080')
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='password']").send_keys('tnrud3080')
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.btn_apply').click()

time.sleep(2)
driver.get('https://ggl-maxim.com/api/popup/popup_menu.asp?mobile=0&lobby=EVOLUTION')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it("gameIframe"))
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".svg--1nrnH")))
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".wrapper--1zUtU button>span")))
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".wrapper--1zUtU button").click()
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'iframe[src^="https://evo.kplaycasino.com/frontend/evo/r2/#category"]')))
iframe2 = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('iframe[src^="https://evo.kplaycasino.com/frontend/evo/r2/#category"]')
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe2)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".svg--1nrnH")))
```